# Rails + Thinking-Sphinx result ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Hey. I use Rails 3.0.1 with thinking-sphinx.

How can I get a list of IDs from a sphinx request? If I do

```
MyModel.search('boby').map(&:id)
```

it makes a request to the database which is redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `search_for_ids`method to return just the primary key values, instead of instances of ActiveRecord objects.

```
MyModel.search_for_ids 'body'
```